# PyQt5 - Rect item don't show up

Tags: python, pyqt5

I think there is nothing wrong in my code, but no way to make that rectangle (last line) appear in my scene...

Here is the main file:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from node_editor import NodeEditor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = NodeEditor()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

NodeEditor() is this file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from node_graphics_scene import QDMGraphicsScene


class NodeEditor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        #Graphics scene
        self.grScene = QDMGraphicsScene()

        #Graphics view
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.grScene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setWindowTitle("KOMAGOMA")
        self.show()

        self.addDebugContent()

    def addDebugContent(self):
        greenBrush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        outlinePen = QPen(Qt.black)
        outlinePen.setWidth(2)


        rect = self.grScene.addRect(-100, -100, 80, 100, outlinePen, greenBrush)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
```

QDMGraphicsScene is this file:

```
import math

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class QDMGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        #Settings
        self.gridSize = 20
        self.gridSquares = 5

        self._color_background = QColor('#1E1E1E')
        self._color_dark = QColor('#151414')
        self._color_light = QColor('#151414')

        self._pen_light = QPen(self._color_light)
        self._pen_light.setWidth(1)
        self._pen_dark = QPen(self._color_dark)
        self._pen_dark.setWidth(2)

        self.scene_width, self.scene_height = 64000, 64000
        self.setSceneRect(-self.scene_width//2, self.scene_height//2, self.scene_width, self.scene_height)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(self._color_background)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)

        #Create grid
        left = int(math.floor(rect.left()))
        right = int(math.ceil(rect.right()))
        top = int(math.floor(rect.top()))
        bottom = int(math.ceil(rect.bottom()))

        first_left = left - (left % self.gridSize)
        first_top = top - (top % self.gridSize)

        #Compute lines to be drawn
        lines_dark, lines_light = [], []
        for x in range(first_left, right, self.gridSize):
            if(x % (self.gridSize * self.gridSquares) != 0): lines_light.append(QLine(x, top, x, bottom))
            else: lines_dark.append(QLine(x, top, x, bottom))

        for y in range(first_top, bottom, self.gridSize):
            if(y % (self.gridSize * self.gridSquares) != 0): lines_light.append(QLine(left, y, right, y))
            else: lines_dark.append(QLine(left, y, right, y))

        #Draw the lines
        painter.setPen(self._pen_light)
        painter.drawLines(*lines_light)

        painter.setPen(self._pen_dark)
        painter.drawLines(*lines_dark)
```

I'm following a tutorial to learn PyQt5.
I follow all along but in my case it doesn't work.
Maybe it had an update and this is not the right way of doing it now?

Comment: What is that `QDMGraphicsScene`? Please provide a valid [mre], we cannot provide answers if you use custom objects we know nothing about.

Comment: Sorry, check the edit.

Comment: You're putting the item outside the scene rect. The scene rect origins at `-32000, 32000`, but you're creating the item at `-100, -100`: check the y coordinates, you missed a minus sign in `setSceneRect()`.

Comment: Oh god, thank you, what a stupid mistake, thank you so much!